# Strange issue with setter

Tags: swift, core-data, set, setter

I have this code and whenever i am running app it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I printed values for self.state and newValue.rawValue by po in terminal of XCode and they have values but i dont understand why i am getting "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error and "CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named for entity Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead". I am getting this error when I do following

```
d.change = .n  //d is just instance of class from where state comes
```

What can be a reason?

```
var change: A {         
        get { return (A(rawValue: self.state) ?? .none)! }
        set { self.state = newValue.rawValue }
    }

enum A: Int16 { 
    case a = 1
    case b = 2
    case c = 3
    case n = 90
}
```

state is a property of class which inherits from NSManagedObject

```
@NSManaged var state: Int16
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Unable to load class named for entity Class` error means that you have created the entity in the Core Data model editor but that you didn't tell it what class name to use. Core Data doesn't know that the class `Class` is used with the entity `Class`, because the names don't have to be the same so Core Data doesn't assume they are. So it uses a plain old `NSManagedObject`, but warns you about it.

You can't use properties of `Class` because you don't have one, so your app crashes.

You fix this by going to the Core Data model editor and making sure that the class name for the entity is correct.